# Polynomial ring indexed by an arbitrary set.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $B$ be any non-empty set, possibly uncountable. What does the term a polynomial ring indexed by the set $B$ means?

Comment: What is the context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like $k[X]$ is "the most general commutative $k$-algebra generated by an element $X$", $k[X_b]_{b\in B}$ is the most general commutative $k$-algebra generated by elements $X_b$ indexed by $B$.

It elements are (finite) formal combinations of monomials $X_{b_1}^{\alpha_1}\cdots X_{b_r}^{\alpha_r}$ where the $X_b$ are your indeterminates (with $b\in B$). The multiplication is the obvious one : you multiply the monomials by adding the powers, and you extend that to general polynomials by bilinearity.

---

Formally, if $\mathbb{N}^{(B)}$ is the set of functions $B\to \mathbb{N}$ with finite support (ie only a finite number of elements of $B$ have non-zero image), then $k[X_b]_{b\in B}$ may be constructed as the set of maps $\mathbb{N}^{(B)}\to k$ with finite support, with its usual $k$-vector space structure, and the product $(f\ast g)(x) = \sum_{a+b=x} f(a)g(b)$.

It can also be characterized as the free $k$-algebra on the set $B$, which means it satisfies the universal property that for any commutative $k$-algebra $A$, and any function $f:B\to A$, there is a unique extension of $f$ to a $k$-algebra morphism $\tilde{f}:k[X_b]_{b\in B}\to A$ (satisfying $\tilde{f}(X_b) = f(b)$).

Comment: thanks! what would the "subalgebra generated by a set B" would mean then? (in the context of formal series) would this be just finite formal combinations of monomials b_1 * b_2 ... * b_n where b_i are in B? or what is the precise definition?

Comment: Yes, that would be it, but they are not really formal anymore, since your $b_i$ are real elements of a bigger algebra.

Comment: thanks so much; I've added another question in case you have time.